# Mass updates in SQL table

Tags: sql, syntax, ssms

We are changing the customers that are aligned to each of our sales reps, I need to create a where clause that would incorporate hundreds of OR statements. Is there a way to easily do this without having to type WHERE "ColumnA" = X OR WHERE "ColumnA" = Y hundreds of times? I have the data in excel but don't know an easy way to concatenate all of this in a format that SQL would accept.

Comment: Provide a sample of your excel input and your desired sql statement. If the excel data are in one row, then it's easy. If you need to span multiple rows, then it may require a little work. But in the end, you want the sql format to look like this: dbms_col_value in ('Jeff','Susie','Ahmad','Chuy'). The IN statement treats those values as "or's".

Comment: Probably a correlated exists with a table of values. You need to provide a lot more detal with sample table/data and your current query.